# Use the letter ñ in C

Tags: c

I have to save in a char[] the letter ñ and I'm not being able to do it. I tried doing this:

```
char example[1];
example[0] = 'ñ';
```

When compiling I get this:

```
$ gcc example.c
error: character too large for enclosing
  character literal type
    example[0] = 'ñ';
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Maybe use *TCHAR*

Comment: I have to use char :(

Comment: Your problem is not "save it", you are doing in the right way, your problem is display it

Comment: Unicode symbol won't fit into a single char, you can store it in multiple chars

Comment: wchar_t x = 'ñ';

Comment: No. When I run this:

    gcc example.c

I get this error:

error: character too large for enclosing
      character literal type
        example[0] = 'ñ';

Comment: this [chart](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/enie-spanish-enye-lowercase-letter-n-tilde-ascii-code-164.html) shows that 'ñ' can be represented in extended ascii as 164.

Comment: @jdigital can I save extended ASCII in a char[] ? I wasn't able to do it.

Comment: The proper answer to this question depends on your compiler and environment.

Comment: @NicolasTinte you'd have to try it.  `example[0] = (char)164`

Comment: Compiler gcc running un High Sierra

Comment: @jdigital that didn't throw the compiling error :D But now, how do I print it? Submit your comment as an answer!

Comment: @NicolasTinte the same way you print any character.  how about: `putchar((char)164)` or `putchar(example[0])`?

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: You need to be aware of [`-fexec-charset`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html) (the character encoding that string and char literals will be emited in). Also, be aware of `-finput-charset` (the character encoding of your entire source file), but that is clearly not the issue in this case.  Anyway, that's the problem. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49470935/2226988) is given by @Jonathan.

Comment: @jdigital There is no one character set known as "Extended ASCII". With computerized text, exactly one character encoding is used and that must be known to all parties. Saying "Extended ASCII" doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "extended ascii".  This [chart](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/enie-spanish-enye-lowercase-letter-n-tilde-ascii-code-164.html) shows that 'ñ' can be represented in extended ascii as 164.

```
example[0] = (char)164;
```

You can print this character just like any other character

```
putchar(example[0]);
```

*As noted in the comments above, this will depend on your environment.  It might work on your machine but not another one.*

The better answer is to use unicode, for example:

```
wchar_t example = '\u00F1';
```

Comment: This answer should not have been accepted, as it's very dated and wrong on any modern system, and from the diagnostic the compiler gave, clearly wrong on OP's system.

Comment: @R.. it was accepted because it worked for the OP.  i would not recommend that anyone use this answer in a "real" program (as mentioned in the second half of the answer).  i certainly wouldn't write code like this.  let's hope that the OP reads the whole discussion and understands this.

Comment: It made the compile error go away, but it's unlikely it worked.

Comment: @R.. the OP stated that it worked (and for that matter, it worked on my computer).

Comment: Sure, it outputs a byte with value 164. That's not a ñ on any system still shipping today except Windows (with its legacy "ANSI codepage" stuff because they refuse to support UTF-8). OSX is always UTF-8, and all modern Linux distros default to UTF-8.

Comment: There is no such thing as "extended ASCII". ASCII is always 7-bit and there is no one standard which defines what the 8th (or 7th, depending on how you count) bit means. Please *don't* use "extended ASCII" to mean code pages or any of the UTFs, since "extended ASCII" implies that these methods of character encoding are - in some way - compatible with ASCII, which is simply not true and adds to the lots of confusion regarding character encoding.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using [High Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49470783/use-the-letter-%c3%b1-in-c/49470935?noredirect=1#comment85944221_49470783), you are presumably using a Mac running macOS 10.13.3 (High Sierra), the same as me.

This comes down to code sets and locales — and can get tricky.  Mac terminals use UTF-8 by default and `ñ` is Unicode character U+00F1, which requires two bytes, 0xC3 and 0xB1, to represent it in UTF-8.  And the compiler is letting you know that one byte isn't big enough to hold two bytes of data. (In the single-byte code sets such as ISO 8859-1 or 8859-15, ñ has character code 0xF1 — 0xF1 and U+00F1 are similar, and this is not a coincidence; Unicode code points U+0000 to U+00FF are the same as in ISO 8859-1.  ISO 8859-15 is a more modern variant of 8859-1, with the Euro symbol € and 7 other variations from 8859-1.)

Another option is to change the character set that your terminal works with; you need to adapt your code to suit the code set that the terminal uses.

You can work around this by using `wchar_t`:

```
#include <wchar.h>

void function(void);

void function(void)
{
    wchar_t example[1];
    example[0] = L'ñ';
    putwchar(example[0]);
    putwchar(L'\n');
}

#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    function();
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles; if you omit the call to `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`, it doesn't work as I want (it generates just octal byte `\361` (aka `0xF1`) and a newline, which generates a `?` on the terminal), whereas with `setlocale()`, it generates two bytes (`\303\261` in octal, aka `0xC3` and `0xB1`) and you see `ñ` on the console output.

Comment: If you define function() above main(), what is the need for the prototype?

Comment: @machine_1: I use `-Wmissing-prototypes` — I either make the function `static` or declare it before defining it.  This time, I included the declaration before the definition (mainly because I wasn't originally going to include the `main()` program — and making it static without using it would also be a compilation error); usually, I'd make the function `static`.  I have no plans to change my default compilation options; you may do as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on which character set / locale you will be using. If you want to hardcode this as a latin1 character, this example program does that:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    char example[2] = {'\xF1'};
    printf("%s", example);
    return 0;
}
```

This, however, results in this output on my system that uses UTF-8:

```
$ ./a.out 
�
```

So if you want to use non-ascii strings, I'd recommend not representing them as char arrays directly. If you *really* need to use char directly, the UTF-8 sequence for `ñ` is two chars wide, and can be written as such (again with a terminating '\0' for good measure):

```
char s[3] = {"\xC3\xB1"};
```