# check if a character in string is Ñ

Tags: c

There is a way to do something like this?

```
    char foo[] = "HOLA Ñ MUNDO";
    int coord = -1, i = 5;
    printf("%c\n",foo[i]); //Always return "�"
    if (foo[i] == 'Ñ')
        coord = 14; //It's like A is the first letter of alphabet, B is the second one, and so on...
    printf("coord:%d\n",coord); //Always return -1, so, foo[i] != 'Ñ' (but it is...)
```

I tried using `#include <locale.h>` and calling the function `setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");` but it doesn't work.

Comment: First, `Ñ` is at index 5 in that array, not index 6. Second, are you sure it's a single byte character in your encoding?

Comment: @Carl Norum My fault. Looks like it's not, because M is the 8th character.

Comment: There you go, then! =)

Comment: Your compiler should be telling you that line 4 you show contains a character that is too large for a character type, implying it's a multi-byte character. You need to either use single-byte characters only or employ multi-byte techniques.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49470935/1216776

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, thanks to the comments from @Carl Norum and @Jeff Holt

```
    #include <locale.h>

    ...

    char foo[] = "HOLA Ñ MUNDO";
    int coord = -1, i = 5;
    printf("%c\n",foo[i]); //Always return "�"
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.utf8");
    int char_len = mblen(&foo[i], MB_CUR_MAX);
    if (memcmp(&foo[i], "Ñ", char_len) == 0) //if (foo[i] == 'Ñ')
        coord = 14; //It's like A is the first letter of alphabet, B is the second one, and so on...
    printf("coord:%d\n",coord); //Now it return 14
```